# Service account key is not working for submitting Hive job to Google DataProc Cluster from Intelij Idea

Tags: hive, google-cloud-dataproc, google-api-java-client

Getting this error in IntelliJ:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:588)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:567)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:66)
    at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.get(OperationFutureImpl.java:125)
```

Code:

```java
HiveJob hiveJob = HiveJob.newBuilder()
                .setQueryList(queryList)
                .build();

Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialFilePath));


JobControllerSettings jobControllerSettings = JobControllerSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .setEndpoint(myEndpoint)
                .build();

 try (JobControllerClient jobControllerClient =
                     JobControllerClient.create(jobControllerSettings)) {

            JobPlacement jobPlacement = JobPlacement.newBuilder().setClusterName(clusterName).build();

            Job job = Job.newBuilder().setPlacement(jobPlacement).setHiveJob(hiveJob).build();


            OperationFuture<Job, JobMetadata> submitJobAsOperationAsyncRequest =
                    jobControllerClient.submitJobAsOperationAsync(projectId, region, job);

            Job response = submitJobAsOperationAsyncRequest.get();
}
```